# Overlay image is hidden when tableview scrolls

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView which I use to display images in a grid form. 4 images per row.

The problem I have now is that the overlay which I have to display when an image is selected. (see image). The overlay is removed, or the image is hidden when the tableview scrolls down. The images are still selected, but the overlay is hidden.

How can the tableview be stopped from removing the overlay image when the image is scrolled out of bounds.

[image]

after scrolling the images out of view and back in the image overlays are gone, but images are still selected.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you scroll the "GetCell" method is being called, which causes all the cells to be redrawn (hence why you're "losing" the selection).

When you select an image, you'll need to keep a reference to that image and cell. In the GetCell method, you can then check to see whether the cell to be drawn contains any selected images, if so, ensure that image is drawn as "selected".

Comment: Or, you can just move the "selected" logic into another array. The next time you generate a cell for the table view, look into that array to determine if you need to display a selection mark or now.

Comment: The Devils in the details. I just wondered if there was a way to stop it from redrawing the sells and ignoring the overlay, but doesnt make sense. will have to track them yeah.

Comment: If you stop it from drawing the cells, then any cells that aren't visible won't be drawn when you scroll so best bet is to track them : )